# How to pass long file names as parameters from one batch file to another?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wrote a batch file like this:

```bash
@echo off
echo this is 1.bat
...
for %%f in (*.xls) do call 2.bat "%%f"
...
```

which has to call `2.bat`, as follows:

```bash
@echo off
echo this is 2.bat
...
tool3.exe -p -q -v %1
...
```

It works, EXCEPT for file names that contains spaces.

It works for `file1.xls`, file2.xls, etc. It doesn't work for `file 10 updated spreadsheet.xls`

I do not use PowerShell, it has to be a batch file calling another batch file.

`2.bat` has a lot of commands, that's why it needs to be called, not inserted in `1.bat`

I guess it's only a syntax detail.

Comment: If you `echo %%f` instead of `call 2.bat "%%f"`, does the filename already have quotes around it? If you `echo %1` in 2.bat, is there only one set of quotes? If there are two sets of quotes (`""file 10 updated spreadsheet.xls""`), this is a one-character fix. If there's only one set of quotes, then it seems that `tool3.exe` does not allow quoted paths, which means you need to either rename the file before running the script or stop using awful software.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, SomethingDark. I just tested it and there is "only one" set of quotes. By the way, I could not rename the files, there are a thousand and they are used by other applications. Tool3.exe is just a nickname for another program. Please tell me the correct syntax for file names with spaces. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What you show in this question should work. It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Thank you, Carey Gregory. It does work as long as the file names don't have any spaces, like the mentioned example. I have tried a lot of things, for hours....

Comment: @Ferreira - putting quotes around the filename _is_ the correct syntax, so as long as the command that is being run is actually `tool3.exe -p -q -v "file 10 updated spreadsheet.xls"`, then the only possible explanation for why it doesn't work is that `tool3.exe` itself doesn't allow quoted paths, which shouldn't be possible because that should be built into Windows. I highly recommend trying to run `tool3.exe -p -q -v "file 10 updated spreadsheet.xls"` on the command line to see if that runs correctly.

Comment: I am trying very hard to to upvote or like your answers and Carey's, but I don't find a link to click on. First time using stack overflow, that's why. Well, thank you and thank you @Carey Gregory.

Comment: I tested it with files that had spaces in the names. It works perfectly fine. I still don't understand what it is that's not working for you. Just saying it doesn't work isn't enough.

Comment: @CareyGregory  After your reply and also Something Dark's reply, I noticed you were both right.  With all those quotes, some of them were not matching. It is working now, and I thank you all. I still don't know how to upvote the answers.

Comment: These aren't answers; they're comments. You can click on the little up arrow thing to the left of a comment to indicate you appreciate it or agree, but it results in no rep change for anyone. It's just a "thanks" which is all any of us expected.

Comment: What would be useful and might earn you some rep is to answer your question yourself. Show us what you found you were doing wrong and what you changed that fixed it. That might help someone else later and you could find yourself getting positive rep from it, maybe even years later.